# Confusing output using DateInterval.day

Tags: vb.net

I confused why my code is not running the right output consistently, This is computation for date format. And im using military time format

- Left digit character represents hours
- decimal represents minutes
- And last is the dateformat

Sample run with 2 digit day format dd:

```
Input 1 is: 3.56
Input 2 is: 21.32 03/13/2014
Output is: 1.28 03/14/2014
```

Sample run with 1 digit day format d. Which is my problem when the day is single digits wrong output:

```
Input 1 is: 3.56
Input 2 is: 21.32 03/07/2014
Output is: 1.33 03/8/2014
```

This is My code:

```
 'if minutes reach 60            
If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then
  TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) + 1 & "." & Val  (TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 60) & " " & Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
  Else
TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)), "##.00") & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)
  End If

'This is for hours convert which if the minutes reach 60
'Problem here
Dim xDate As Date = Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)), "MM/dd/yyyy")

 If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) >= 24 Then
TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) - 24 & "." & Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) & " " & DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, xDate)
End If
```

Comment: Yes I think because im using Vb.net sorry about my code Im just a beginner with this vb.net came from java

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .NET formats:

```
Console.WriteLine( date.ToString("h:mm dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

See on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more details about available formats

Comment: Will I replace this code Dim xDate As Date = Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)), "MM/dd/yyyy")
 And change it to that?